# Maximal normal subgroup has prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am trying to solve the following exercise taken from Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*:

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Prove that if $M \lhd G$, then $[G:M]$ is finite and equal to a prime.

I am completely lost with this exercise, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to prove that the only groups which have *only* two subgroups -- the trivial ones: the unit and the the whole group itself -- are finite (and cyclic)  groups of order a prime number.

Comment: I could show that the order of a group is a prime $p$ if and only if the only subgroups are the trivial ones, as you've suggested. Today I found out about the existence of the correspondence theorem: $G/M$ is in a one to one correspondence with the set $X=\{H \leq G : M \leq H\}=\{M,G\}$ so $[G:M]=|G/M|=|X|=2$, is this correct?

Comment: Almost. I'd say "*the lattice of subgroups of* $\;G/H is...".

Comment: In general, which is the correct "form": The elements of $X$ are in a one to one correspondence with the elements of $Y$, or $X$ is in a one to one correspondence with $Y$? (By your correction I suppose the first form is the correct one.)

Comment: Well, what is your "Y" ? :) The correspondence theorem tells: there is a one to one correspondence between the subgroups of a factor group $\;G/M\;$ and the subgroups of $\;G\;$ containing $\;M\;$, and this correspondence mantains both normality **and index** .

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all, what I meant was: suppose you have a bijective function from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, then, is it correct to say "there is a one to one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$", or the correct form is "there is a one to one correspondence between the elements of $X$ and the elements of $Y$? (english is not my native language btw).

Comment: Both forms between "" are correct, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Starter hint: maximality of $M$ translates into some fact about $G/M$.